# Xamarin.Forms Shell - Cold Start App Opening

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I have a Xamarin.Forms App (v4.3.0.908675) that looks like this:

[image]

It has several tabs and uses a very basic XF Shell for the layout.

It receives several Push Notifications and in one of them the App needs to open a specific tab after the Notification is tapped. The App then it's cold started.

I'm trying the following in order to do that: In my App.xaml.cs I have a method that is called every time a notification is opened that sends a message to the shell in order to select the tab.

```
public App()
{
    // One Signal
    OneSignal.Current.StartInit( "8449c-..." )
    .HandleNotificationOpened(HandleNotificationOpened)
    .EndInit();
}

// When a push notification is opened
private void HandleNotificationOpened( OSNotificationOpenedResult result )
{
    Messenger.Default.Send( new ServiceScheduleMessage(), "LoadSectionDeepLink" );  
}
```

Then in my AppShell.xaml.cs I receive the message and change the default tab:

```
//* loading service schedules deep link
private void LoadServiceSchedulesDeepLink()
{
    CurrentItem = this.my_service_schedules;
}
```

However, when I do that the App opens like this:

[image]

The tabs are gone, and if tap on some of the buttons that navigate to other pages, the App crashes. It seems like I changed the tab before the Shell was ready and caused this weird behavior.

Question:

Is there a way to know that the App has finished started so I can call some other method like change the current Shell Tab?

Comment: Have you tried using the `App.xaml.cs` class for this? There is a method called OnStart that triggers on application load completion

Comment: About [Lifecycle methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/app-lifecycle) of Xamarin Forms App , you can have a try with `OnStart` method to invoke some other method as FreakyAli said.

Comment: Thanks both for your comments. I could use the OnStart, however I need some of the data that comes with the Push Notification (One Signal). I think a need a combination of both methods; I'm trying something If I succeed I can post my findings here.

Comment: @LuisdeHaro OK , if test in iOS platform , here is [the lifecyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/application-lifecycle-demo#walkthrough) of iOS device for reference .